# Is there a good set of use cases for a client to a typical version control system?

Tags: version-control, cvs, use-case

Can anyone recommend a reference (online or book) for using a client of a VCS (RCS/CVS/SVN/Git/etc.) from the perspective of high-level use cases?

By "high-level" I mean a daily value-added perspective (e.g., the "Boss test" use-case level), as opposed to low-level use cases for commands like commit or update.

I found [VCS Use Cases for NetBeans](http://ui.netbeans.org/nonav/docs/hi/promoF/vcs-usecases.html), but I think it's incomplete. There are no use cases on resolving conflicts after an update, performing diffs, etc., which is value-added stuff and not syntax-related (also not trivial!).

The [Eclipse Team CVS tutorial](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-60_team.htm) is helpful for resolving conflicts, but is very specific to that tool.

Anyone know of a book that describes the high-level scenarios well?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by use cases?  Are you thinking of things like: tagging, branching, etc or something else?

Comment: Have a look at the NetBeans link for exactly what I mean by use cases. The Eclipse tutorial I mentioned has documented cases (in tutorial form) for "Working with conflicting changes". It has most of the variants (conflicting changes to the same file at different lines, conflicting changes to the same file at the same line). These are perhaps the **trickiest** use-cases to understand in a VCS. Are there others? File removed in repository but still needed in local version, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the big ones I came up with. I liked the explanations given in [Chapter 6 of Head First Software Development](http://www.oreilly.de/catalog/9780596527358/chapter/ch06.pdf). I generated this image using [PlantUML](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/form?url=TP0nRiCm34Lt0xu3aIaPSe6ixGq2TCf2IzyEOLaoADg8M_H0FKSlLXcjKw15Deby91yPq1fP8fNkQkH5uKnIhAlSInnPUQ2HNSyTphO4q9glAtQMb9un8wGHIfp9rzKFIBiNQ2vDw2b5qnJel6J3iAEtkl9qFD9UefXma5TGvkYRT3lGYToSoLtX-ZJPHfPva1abph53th1fz6pO8ASelxyCUt-9wqE7Izn_VdWnJ4g6c-6mbNBai1GDBsqBHNI_zMjemmPezq3YSM-thY_Dz5_DfM6G-uuUhKIGSTV1q_nzl0qjqRj4aIqMZN8iPyfbpliN). 
[image]